# Kinect laser range - strange values

Tags: kinect, laser, turtlebot, sensor-msgs, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get several value from my turtlebot's kinect laser (specifically the left-most and right-most laser ranges).  I'm currently reading the sensor_msgs/LaserScan ranges array for those values.  If I cover the laser with my hand, the values are read as 11 for some reason - can anyone explain this?  Also, it seems like the laser doesn't fire as far as it possibly can - if I put the turtlebot in the middle of a room, the range values reported are also 11 (most of the time - if I put an object a few feet in front of the turtlebot, some of the ranges change.  Is there a way to extend or set the kinect's laser range?  Could someone clear this up for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31426/kinect-laser-range---strange-values./) by [AmaneSuzuha](https://answers.ros.org/users/1879/amanesuzuha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is that Kinect doesn't use single laser beams to get the distance, but a laser image, that is projected into the room.
A camera slightly apart from this laser image source 'sees' this image from a slightly different angle and can hence calculate the distances.
To do this successfully, objects must have a minimum distance to the Kinect - usually 60cm.

That the sensor reports 11m, when you cover it with your hand, means it has no reasonable values to offer and reports invalid ones.
Have a look at *range_max* value. It will pretty sure be *10m* in your case.

If that's the case, everything is ok.
Although there should be reasonable values in the laser array, if distances in front of the camera range from 60cm - 6m.

---

Originally posted by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) with karma: 237 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1